# Как парсить динамический контент на сайте

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup

Есть некий контент на странице: [image: Это размеры одежды которые есть и те которых не осталось]

> Это размеры одежды которые есть и те которых не осталось

Чем нужно парсить страницу чтобы получить точные данные

[Вот ссылка на пример страницы](https://www.trendyol.com/altinyildiz-classics/erkek-siyah-anti-pilling-tuylenme-yapmayan-standart-fit-bato-yaka-soguk-gecirmez-polar-sweatshirt-p-51325257)
Вот HTML код с страницы: [image: Это код контента о размерах]

> И пожалуйста будьте добры укажите если я плохо задал вопрос. Я уверен что написал плохой вопрос и прошу прощение за это

Comment: playwright, selenium

Comment: Вы знаете другой способ подгрузки javascript? Ваш ответ не подходит под задачу мне нужно в бота вшить парсер @nexoma

Comment: причем здесь подгрузка яваскрипт? вам следует получить html-документ, распарсить его для получения требуемых html-элементов. если документ формируется динамически, то лучше это сделать через selenium. если документ статический то достаточно, например, requests. получить элементы можно как через xpath, так и с помощью css-selectors.  вот ссылочки для начального знакомства https://dev-gang.ru/article/kak-ispolzovat-python-i-xpath-dlja-czistki-saitov-ht13ju9mu8/   https://habr.com/ru/post/250975/  https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/index.html  по playwright найдёте сами.